# Modx, как увеличить размер загружаемого контента

Tags: modx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте подскажите как увеличить размер загружаемого контента в modx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна системная настройка `upload_maxsize`, ищите ее в верхнем меню, в правом углу - иконка "шестеренки", далее поиск по названию настройки. Увеличьте значение до желаемого (разумеется, не должно противоречить серверным настройкам)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Tarason, не подскажите в чём проблема, был бы очень признателен.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1385511/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-ajaxform-%d0%b2-modx

Comment: @Vadim Ответил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Anton Tarasov, спасибо большое