# Не работает AjaxForm в modx

Tags: modx

В Formit вроде показывает отправленные формы, но ajax и отправка на почту не работает, что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код шаблона:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код чанка form_contacts:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код чанка email_tpl:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте пока без AjaxForm установить и вызвать сниппет QuickEmail, что он сообщит: [[!QuickEmail? &debug=`1`]]

Comment: Anton Tarasov, Вот что получилось: prnt.sc/MC_VrmZnINpo. 
Письма нашёл в рассылках: prnt.sc/akmpIqskPUQB.

Comment: @Anton Tarasov, а не подскажите почему страница перезагружается, обёртка AjaxForm не срабатывает или я что-то не так понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: 1) уберите параметр `&spamCheckIP` 2)уберите хук `spam` в `hooks`, попробуйте еще раз попробовать отправить письмо. письмо не попадает в спам? ящик существует? в домене? Также можете сгенерировать здесь https://www.mail-tester.com/ адрес и указать его в `&emailTo`, затем нажать на кнопку в сервисе и проверить все почтовые заголовки(если письмо дойдет), может в них какая проблема.

Comment: По поводу перезагрузки страницы- в консоли браузера что-то есть? Вам нужно попробовать обрабатывать событие af_complete, как указано здесь: https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/ajaxform

Comment: @Anton Tarasov, спасибо, jquery не был подключен

Comment: отлично, отметьте пожалуйста флажком решение